# How to change progressbar's span/div width automatically?

Tags: jquery, dynamic, progress-bar, width

I made this simple html snippet: `<div class="progress-bar"></div>`, then I styled it:

```
.progress-bar {
    background-color: #DFDFDF;
    height: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 6.66667px;
    margin-left: -2px;
    margin-top: -22px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Additionally:

```
<li>
<span class="name">
<a>theme</a>
</span>
<span class="value"> <?=$howtsrg?></span>
<div class="progress-bar"></div>
</li>
```

`<?=$howtsrg?>` **= the value feteched from the database**

Now, I want to give this progressbar a width, but this has to be automatically, depending on the value that is been fetched from the database. For example, I now have a list with a **value** 7 and a value 2... I want to have a different width of the progressbar, because they do not have the same value. How can I make this work? I couldn't find a relevant **jQuery** script.

PS: the list values are dynamic and will change as days go past! So 7 and 2 can be 15 and 22!

Comment: Hi! I don't know how people can answer this question, I don't get it. What exactly is this value? How is the pregressbar updated?...

Comment: The progressbar can't be updated, because there is no script. You have to do that with css, that is logical, right? :) What it is, is not important, it is important to know that it's coming from a database and the progressbar has to change with this value. That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this way. Say, you have got a value like `72`. You can use jQuery to do this way:

```
$(".progress-bar").css("width", "75%");
```

Or, you can do this way:

```
$(".progress-bar").width("75%");
```

#### You need to give `px`: Change width: `<?=$howtsrg?>px;`

Comment: As I said: is this the right way to assign it to a dynamic value? The value will change, that's why... Thank you anyway!

Comment: Yes, this is a better way. You cannot have 100 classes for 100 percentages.

Comment: @user1717526 Use this way: `<div class="progress-bar" style="width: <?=$howtsrg?>;"></div>`

Comment: Thanks Praveen Kumar. Now, it gets only the list items which have a value, which is a good thing to start, but it didn't set the width of them in the right way. They all have the same width now.

Comment: Hey, lemme know the full code, so that I can guide you better?

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but  you wanted the full code, so I posted that :D Now you have an indication of how the code looks like. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/PuM3b/2/

Comment: Why isn't the `"width: <?=$howtsrg?>;"` getting rendered?

Comment: Good question... If I look at it in Firebug, I can see that the width = 7 and width: 2, but it won't change the progressbar. Maybe because there are no pixels after the values or something?

PS: on the fiddle it can't be rendered I guess, because that is php.

Comment: Good that you said this. Change it to: `"width: <?=$howtsrg?>px;"` You forgot the `px` to be suffixed! :)

Comment: Thanks mate, that was the problem!

Comment: I will accept it, but you have to edit your post, because I don't want to accept the wrong answer... People might need it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a percentage:

```
$('.progress-bar').width('50%');
```

To target individual progress bars, you'll need to give them `id`s or select them with a proper selector.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But is this the right way to assign it to a dynamic value? The value will change, that's why... (edited first post)

Comment: You can use an expression: `.width((x / max) * 100 + '%')`. I'm not sure what you mean by "dynamic" here.

Comment: With dynamic I mean that the value will change. It is not staying 7 and 2, but it can be something like 14 and 22.

Comment: That's not helping much. What prevents you from computing the percentage of the progress bar and setting it from within your script every time you change the values?

Comment: I updated my post and gave more information. Maybe that will help.

Comment: See my edit. The progress bar's width needs to be a percentage, which you'll have to output from your server